# Query select minute from current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query (SQL Server)

```
 SELECT Idő, Terem, Leírás, IKód
   FROM Filmlista F, Idopontok I
  WHERE Cím LIKE 'Fűrész'
    AND I.FKód = F.FKód
    AND (Idő >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

**Idő=Date in DB**

I want to that

```
SELECT Date 
FROM DB 
WHERE DATE >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-30 minute)
```

How can I write this query?

For example: today's date is `2014-07-01 15:00:00` and date in DB `2014-07-01 16:00:00` at 15:29 o clock it select `2014-07-01 16:00:00` but when 15:31 its not

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: From the last sentence it seems that the time on your computer and the time on the DB Server differ by one hour, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as long as you have proper key columns (that is, `FKód`) in your tables, I would recommend using an `INNER JOIN`. Next, if you are looking for an exact match on the film's title (namely, *Saw* & *Saw 2* are different films [or in Hungarian: *Fűrész* és *Fűrész 2*]), then use the `=` operator:

```
    SELECT Idő, Terem, Leírás, IKód
      FROM Filmlista AS f
INNER JOIN Idopontok AS i ON ( f.FKód = i.FKód )
     WHERE Cím = 'Fűrész'
       AND Idő >= DateAdd(minute, -30, GetDate())
```

If you want to return all films starting with the name *Saw* (*Fűrész*), then you should use the `LIKE` operator:

```
    SELECT Idő, Terem, Leírás, IKód
      FROM Filmlista AS f
INNER JOIN Idopontok AS i ON ( f.FKód = i.FKód )
     WHERE Cím LIKE 'Fűrész%'
       AND Idő >= DateAdd(minute, -30, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this, if I understand you correctly!

```
    SELECT Idő,Terem,Leírás,IKód 
    FROM Filmlista F,Idopontok I 
    WHERE Cím like 'Fűrész' AND I.FKód=F.FKód 
    AND (Idő>=dateadd(minute, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: it's not working :/ it listed all date from my db where `Cím like 'Fűrész'`

Comment: i wrote an example in post

Comment: @Sanyaetrone, i have edited my answer and added opening and closing parenthesis to to bind the AND components of the where clause together, please chack.

Comment: And to understand why it was returning all data where Cím like 'Fűrész', see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx